# Where do I place side effects in a React app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am building a React app and wanted to determine the cleanest way to achieve the following behavior.

I have a `List` component that renders N `Details` components. Each `Details` component has a `Connect` button component that will trigger some behavior. There are 3 different behaviors:

1. immediately make API call, which requires no state change
2. open a modal and make an API call based on values in the input modal, which involves changing app `State` to render a modal, and then making an API call when they confirm the `modal`
3. open a pop-up window and make an API call based on returned values from that pop-up window.

To achieve this, I can pass down 3 separate callbacks to the `Connect` button component, and switch based on the value of the `Detail` component so it knows which callback to pass. However, this means the `Detail` component has some "switch-on-type" behavior. For example,

```
if (this.props.name === `immediate-connection`) { 
    callbackToPass = this.props.callApi;
} else if (this.props.name === `trigger-modal`) {
    callbackToPass = this.props.changeStateToRenderModal;
}... // etc.
```

I could also build 3 separate components that encapsulate the behavior and have them render from `Details` but this doesn't avoid the switch-on-type behavior.

Another way to phrase this question is how to get identical behavior from the `Connect` buttons when their implementation is different? Do I encapsulate this behavior in a sub-component rendered by the `Connect` button or do I lift it it up to when `State` would be changed?

Comment: "Where do the side effects go?" interesting question. More important question: "where **don't** the side effects go?" They don't mix with presentation code, and they don't mix with data transforming code (those two things also don't mix with each other). Note that if you adhere to those two rules, it's pretty clear that side effects will have to go in a component who's sole job is to produce said side-effect and possibly pass results/conditionally render children.

Comment: It usually goes in [middleware](https://redux.js.org/advanced/middleware) if you use redux or [useEffect](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) hook. If you use effect hook then don't mix it with jsx and add Container to the name so you know it's a container. The hook example didn't get this right to simplify the examle.